# Search in meteor using Easy Search Error: MinimongoEngine

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-easy-search

I am currently using this guide to perform an easy search on weather.

http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/

It generates an error like the following:

```
TypeError: MinimongoEngine is not a constructor
```

This is how I am implementing the search:

Packages installed:

```
matteodem:easy-search
easy:search
easysearch:components
easysearch:core
```

client/searchBox.html

```
<template name="searchBox">
    {{> EasySearch.Input index=playersIndex }}
    <ul>
        {{#EasySearch.Each index=playersIndex }}
            <li>Name of the player: {{name}}</li>
        {{/EasySearch.Each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

client/searchBox.js

```
// On Client
Template.searchBox.helpers({
  playersIndex: () => PlayersIndex,
})
```

lib/collection.js

```
import { Index, MinimongoEngine } from 'meteor/easy:search'

// On Client and Server
const Players = new Mongo.Collection('players')
const PlayersIndex = new Index({
  collection: Players,
  fields: ['name'],
  engine: new MinimongoEngine()
})
```

Some idea of how to solve it, I’m new to meteor, so any help would be appreciated. If I’m doing something wrong, please help.

Answer (score 1):

ar, I don't know how you have solved or left that but I have solved as like using `EasySearch.MongoDB` & importing `EasySearch`

```
import { EasySearch } from 'meteor/easy:search'

export const EventsIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
   collection: Events,
   fields: ['title', 'description'],
   engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the github example [code](https://github.com/matteodem/easy-search-leaderboard/blob/aad21bc57aa20ed852e0325302a2e8fbf9cc8f44/imports/api/players/players_index.js) `MongoDBEngine` is used instead of `MinimongoEngine`.

Looking at the package source it looks like both `MinimongoEngine` and `MongoDBEngine` are exported. Could it be that it wants `MinimongoEngine` on the client and `MongoDBEngine` in the server context? Is that type error showing up in the server console or in your browser console?